# Finding adjacently repeated "and" in a sentence using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string "***this is a boy and and and and girl or biscut and pen***" I would like to replace all these `and`s by a single `and`. Can this be done by using Regex?

I was using this regex but it fails:

```
@"\b(?<word>\w+)\s+(\k<word>)\b"
```

Comment: Your regex is correct for replacing exactly two occurrences of the same word (any word). The parens around `\k<word>` are unnecessary, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(\band\s+)+", "and ");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean repeated words in general (as the regex in your post suggests):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1)+\b", "$1");
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b    # Assert start at a word boundary
(\w+) # Match a word
(?:   # Try to match...
 \s+  # Whitespace and
 \1   # the same word as before
)+    # one or more times
\b    # Assert end at a word boundary
```

If it's only `and` you want to replace:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\b(?:and\s+){2,}", "and ");
```

Comment: Not in general Only checking "and" only

Comment: +1 for breaking down the RegEx.  Useful for folks who don't have much experience with them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe: `@"(\band\s+){2,}"` (untested though). Or, since you're search/replacing anyway, `@"(\band\s+)+"`.